# How to check OS version in a cross platform fashion with C++?

Tags: c++, string, operating-system

Well, I think the question is fairly objective. So, is there anyway to do it?

Actually, I need to check what version of the OS because I want to get a directory from a string:

```
"directory/file.ext"
```

or

```
"directory\file.ext"
```

So I split one of those strings according to "\" or to "/", depending on which OS I'm dealing with.

I'm quite new to C++ and I don't know if there's another way of *getting a directory from a path string*.

I can do that fairly well with C#, which will be my last alternative.

Best regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do it with Qt, it will take care of all the cross platform stuff for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to do that.  The POSIX style "/" will work as a directory separator just fine, even on a Win32 system (try it out.)

That said, other filesystem operations are platform-specific (drive letters, for instance.)

The Boost Filesystem library is a good option - code to this, and it will handle the platform details for you: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

Other cross-platform C++ frameworks, such as Qt, have similar facilities.

You can delve into more details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

Comment: even for the splitting of the string? I don't think so... I'll get a "\" as input when on Windows and a "/" as input when on Linux...

Comment: I see - if you're parsing paths for use in your program, and not using a path-normalizing library like Boost Filesystem, then you either need to check for both, or use the #ifdef WIN32, as Miguel suggests.  This is fine to do at compile-time, since a C++ binary for windows will not run on Linux (except via Wine or an emulator, in which case "\" paths are fine).

Comment: Yes, I thought about that after posting the comment... Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `#ifdef WIN32` to decide if you are on Windows. This works even on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: That would check on compile time... I'd like a runtime directive... Much like the Environment.OSVersion on C#

Comment: Why?  Since you cannot build once and deploy to both Windows and linux unless you are using Wine which would still expect the Windows style paths...

Comment: Yes, I thought about that after posting the comment... Sorry!